# Loop through object and print values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object `video` for the view of my node.js app which contains the following.

```
{ title: 
       [ 'Jason Fried: Why work doesn\'t happen at work',
         'John Maeda: How art, technology and design inform creative leaders',
         'From Storytelling to Storylistening: John Maeda (Future of StoryTelling 2014)' ],
      url: 
       [ 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XD2kNopsUs&feature=youtu.be',
         'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAuDCOl9qrk&feature=youtu.be',
         'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8-Q70gV2Yk&feature=youtu.be' ] }
```

I'm trying to loop through these keys and print all the values but I'm not sure if my approach is on the right track.
Because I get nothing printed.

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < video.length; i++) { 

    var videoAtr = video[i]; 

    for (var key in videoAtr) { %>
    <li>
        <%= video[i][key] %>
    </li>
    <% }
} %>
```

**UPDATE**

I'd like to print like the following way.

title[0] url[0]

title[1] url[1]

title[2] url[2]

Comment: An associative array in JavaScript is nothing but an object. Look up how to loop through an object

Comment: Well, what do you want/expect to be displayed?

Comment: try video.title.length and video.title[i]

Comment: you can use this  for (var i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
                                console.log("key and value" + video[i]["Key"], video[i]["Value"]);

                            }

Comment: Please see the update on my question that I described how I need them displayed.

Answer (score 2):

As associative arrays are objects in JavaScript you can do this

```
for (var key in p) {
   if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
  }
 }
```

The if condition is to check if the property comes from the prototype which will not be needed as your object stands above

---

The reason your code doesn't work is because since it is an object, it doesn't store a length property

---

**EDIT**

To get the `<li>` to show

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < video.length; i++) { %>
    <li>
    <%for (var key in video) { %>
        <%= video[key][i] %>
    <% }%>
    </li>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting all the values now but I would like to print them in groups like this `<li>title[0] url[0]</li><li>title[1] url[1]</li><li>title[2] url[2]</li>` How do I achieve that?

Comment: try to render list in loop

Comment: @SeongLee. I don't know if this is too late but I updated the answer